# importing financial statements from getFin() to data.frame or data.table?

Tags: r, quantmod

the getFin() function returns an object of type "financials". which contains a list of lists.

```
getFin("AAPL")
```

[structure of resulting object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0m76.png)

i need to create tables for each of the following:

- Balance Sheet
- Income Statement
- Cash Flow

End goal is to display these tables on a dashboard.
Here's what I tried, but it doesn't seem right:

```
df <- data.frame(AAPL.f[[2]][2])
df2 <- data.frame(viewFin(AAPL.f,"BS", "A"))
```

How can I get the above statements into Data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want.

```
require(quantmod)
setwd("C:/Users/your_path_here/downloads")
stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO","CVX","DD","DIS","GE","GS","HD","IBM","INTC","JNJ","JPM","KO","MCD","MMM","MRK","MSFT","NKE","PFE","PG","T","TRV","UNH","UTX","V","VZ","WMT","XOM")

# equityList <- read.csv("EquityList.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# names(equityList) <- c ("Ticker")

for (i in 1 : length(stocks)) {   
        temp<-getFinancials(stocks[i],src="google",auto.assign=FALSE)
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Quarterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
}
```

Comment: this is not the exact solution I was looking for. but it is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I was looking for....
I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

```
library(quantmod)
library(xlsx)
getFin("GS")
gs_BS <- GS.f$BS$A
str(gs_BS)

 #num [1:42, 1:4] 106533 NA 113003 71883 NA ...
 #- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 # ..$ : chr [1:42] "Cash & Equivalents" "Short Term Investments" "Cash and Short Term Investments" "Accounts Receivable - Trade, Net" ...
 # ..$ : chr [1:4] "2015-12-31" "2014-12-31" "2013-12-31" "2012-12-31"
 #- attr(*, "col_desc")= chr [1:4] "As of 2015-12-31" "As of 2014-12-31" "As of 2013-12-31" "As of 2012-12-31"

transposed <- t(gs_BS)
write.xlsx(transposed, "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\bal_sheet.xlsx", row.names=FALSE)
transp <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Tatter\\Desktop\\bal_sheet.xlsx" , sheetName="Sheet1")
transp$year <- c("2015","2014","2013","2012")

#> str(transp)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  43 variables:
#$ Cash...Equivalents                          : num  106533 90406 94224 65919
#$ Short.Term.Investments                      : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Cash.and.Short.Term.Investments             : num  113003 96196 98364 72669
#$ Accounts.Receivable...Trade..Net            : num  71883 94479 97880 91354
#$ Receivables...Other                         : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Total.Receivables..Net                      : num  71883 94479 97880 91354
#$ Total.Inventory                             : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Prepaid.Expenses                            : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Other.Current.Assets..Total                 : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Total.Current.Assets                        : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Property.Plant.Equipment..Total...Gross     : num  17726 18324 18236 17267
#$ Accumulated.Depreciation..Total             : num  -7770 -8980 -9040 -9050
#$ Goodwill..Net                               : num  3657 3645 3705 3702
#$ Intangibles..Net                            : num  491 515 671 1397
#$ Long.Term.Investments                       : num  548317 547272 615841 602819
#$ Other.Long.Term.Assets..Total               : num  5548 5181 5241 55291
#$ Total.Assets                                : num  861395 855842 911507 938555
#$ Accounts.Payable                            : num  210362 213572 204765 194485
#$ Accrued.Expenses                            : num  8149 8368 7874 8292
#$ Notes.Payable.Short.Term.Debt               : num  196752 186133 250283 241931
#$ Current.Port..of.LT.Debt.Capital.Leases     : num  29623 29501 47288 67349
#$ Other.Current.liabilities..Total            : num  1280 1533 1974 2724
#$ Total.Current.Liabilities                   : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Long.Term.Debt                              : num  268652 257954 245227 176270
#$ Capital.Lease.Obligations                   : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Total.Long.Term.Debt                        : num  268652 257954 245227 176270
#$ Total.Debt                                  : num  495027 473588 542798 485550
#$ Deferred.Income.Tax                         : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Minority.Interest                           : num  459 404 326 508
#$ Other.Liabilities..Total                    : num  51035 70829 70120 152289
#$ Total.Liabilities                           : num  774667 773045 833040 862839
#$ Redeemable.Preferred.Stock..Total           : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Preferred.Stock...Non.Redeemable..Net       : num  11200 9200 7200 6200
#$ Common.Stock..Total                         : num  9 9 8 8
#$ Additional.Paid.In.Capital                  : num  51340 50049 48998 48030
#$ Retained.Earnings..Accumulated.Deficit.     : num  83386 78984 71961 65223
#$ Treasury.Stock...Common                     : num  -62640 -58468 -53015 -46850
#$ Other.Equity..Total                         : num  -718 -743 -524 -520
#$ Total.Equity                                : num  86728 82797 78467 75716
#$ Total.Liabilities...Shareholders..39..Equity: num  861395 855842 911507 938555
#$ Shares.Outs...Common.Stock.Primary.Issue    : logi  NA NA NA NA
#$ Total.Common.Shares.Outstanding             : num  419 430 467 465
#$ year                                        : chr  "2015" "2014" "2013" "2012"

so, the financial statement object has been transposed so that each item on the statement (Balance Sheet in this case) becomes a column and can be written to a database table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ticker = "AAPL"
period = 'A'
statements = getFin(ticker, auto.assign=FALSE)
bs = viewFin(statements, type="BS", period=period)
is = viewFin(statements, type="IS", period=period)
cf = viewFin(statements, type="CF", period=period)
bs.df = data.frame(bs)
is.df = data.frame(is)
cf.df = data.frame(cf)
```

You can then check to make sure they're all of `data.frame` class like so.

```
> is.data.frame(bs.df)
[1] TRUE

> is.data.frame(is.df)
[1] TRUE

> is.data.frame(cf.df)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. the second statement in my snippet does the same thing. Need each item from those statements (list total assets, total income...) as a column on my data frame / data table... if i were to do this let's say, for S&P 500, it'd be easier to lookup any item like "total assets" for any company during any year.

Comment: Is there a python equivalent for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want.

```
require(quantmod)
setwd("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/downloads")
stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO","CVX","DD","DIS","GE","GS","HD","IBM","INTC","JNJ","JPM","KO","MCD","MMM","MRK","MSFT","NKE","PFE","PG","T","TRV","UNH","UTX","V","VZ","WMT","XOM")

# equityList <- read.csv("EquityList.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# names(equityList) <- c ("Ticker")

for (i in 1 : length(stocks)) {   
        temp<-getFinancials(stocks[i],src="google",auto.assign=FALSE)
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Quarterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
}
```